# Yii1 Необходимо вставить содержимое шаблона в страницу по нажатию кнопки

Tags: php, yii

использовал **renderPartial()**, но он стирает все содержимое страницы и выводит шаблон. Мне же необходимо в страницу вставить содержимое шаблона, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Что ты подразумеваешь под содержимым шаблона? Контентную часть?

Comment: Предположим в шаблоне находится изображение и js к нему